# see DNS request hosts from any wireless networks(without knowing password)

Tags: wireless-networking, sniffing

I want to know hosts from DNS requests in any wireless network. Is it possible without knowing wifi passwords ? If yes, please list the steps.

Answer (score 2):

No, without knowing the wireless password, it's not possible to sniff the DNS requests being made on a modern network (typically protected by WPA2-PSK or better).